# Protractor: catch AssertionError

Tags: javascript, protractor, chai, chai-as-promised

I'm using **Protractor** with **Chai as Promised** in order to create a javascript-based testing tool and I'm getting the error

`AssertionError: expected 'http://localhost:8888/test/homepage.php' to equal 'http://localhost:8888/test/my_homepage.php'`

while I'm checking the url with this step definition:

```
this.Then(/^The url of the page should be "([^"]*)"$/, function(myUrl, callback){
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(myUrl);

    callback();
  });
```

I would like to catch this error in order to use a different callback function, how can I do that? I've tried to use a try-catch block but it doesn't seem to work. I can't even understand if `AssertionErrors` are generated by Protractor, can you gently give me an explaination about this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Would `notify` help here: `expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(myUrl).notify(yourcallback)`?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find anything which could catch errors from expect and do something else. If @alecxe's suggestion from comments work, that should be your answer otherwise why not just do

```
browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
    if(url === myUrl) {
       callback();
    } else {
       callback('something went wrong'); 
    }
});
```

or would this not work?

```
try {
  expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(myUrl);
  callback();
} catch(e) {
  callback('something went wrong ')); 
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but callback.fail() is not a recognized as function.

Comment: Looks like they removed `callback.fail()` in 0.7.0. Check [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/eaedca85928f88b20791bf02d61250b3baad88d5/CHANGELOG.md#v070). You might want to just do, `callback(new Error('something went wrong'));`

Comment: The error now is -> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL  :(

Comment: Can you try just putting a string instead of an error object? I updated the answer

Comment: Same result :(
Does exist a documentation where we can find the parameters for a callback?

Comment: In [README](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js#step-definitions) there are bunch of references to `callback(new Error(''));`